# pytest - how to collect fixtures and setup methods before execution of each item

Tags: python, pytest

need help to detect all preconditions for test going to be executable.
I mean there are a lot of pytest_* events but i have not found nothing corresponding to what i need. 
Here is a few lines of code:

```
class TestCreate:

 @classmethod
 def setup_class(cls):
    print('setup_class')

 def setup_method(self, method):
     print('setup_method')

 def test_method0(self, usefull_fixture):
     assert usefull_fixture.x == 1
```

test_method0 have 1 usefull_fixture defined in conftest and 2 setup methods right inside of class. What I need is before test executes collect all features and setup functions and prepare that info for further sending or processing. All I have got in the moment is names of fixtures but neither order nor setup methods I am not able to detect. Maybe any secret hook exists or i need override somewhat behaviour. Best option is to catch event when each precondition executes.

*UPDATE: I need create plugin which can introspect tests were gathered for launch and detect what preconditions for each test are going to be executed. For example i have event pytest_pyfunc_call() but it shows only test methods not setup/teardown methods. The same with other events. How in runtime detect setup/teardown methods for particular test ?

Comment: Could you update the question with what you are actually trying to achieve with the information you are seeking?  I think that would help with finding the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this solves your problem: [xunit style setup](http://pytest.org/latest/xunit_setup.html)

You can define setup/teardown methods at module, class and test levels:

```
def setup_module(module):
    """ setup any state specific to the execution of the given module."""

def teardown_module(module):
    """ teardown any state that was previously setup with a setup_module
    method.
    """
```

EDIT: Did you take a look at http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#pytest-hook-reference? Using those hooks you can customize nearly all of pytest behavior. I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, but I think you can customize exactly how the test will execute by using the `pytest_runtest_protocol`.

Comment: Yes, I've seen these hooks but haven't found nothing out of the box. It seems like one way left - to override builtin class. Thanks for your time.